# (Hugo) Load dynamic Content from Raw GitHub

Tags: github, dynamic-content, hugo

Is there a way to load content into Hugo dynamically from a raw GitHub user content?

e.g.

I if there is an about.md (among other pages) in a repo that is also in the static site but I'd rather not have the duplication and it would help on maintainability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the examples  for the base64 template functions described here:

https://gohugo.io/templates/functions/

`{{ $resp := getJSON "https://api.github.com/repos/spf13/hugo/readme"  }}
{{ $resp.content | base64Decode | markdownify }}`